# How to parallel following sentence?

Tags: sentence-construction, parallelism

In the following sentence, can I remove "them"? I am looking for a way to parallel the second part of the sentence: "... which as...".

> By the appearance of universities' faculties on television, universities win popularity which as a result, more students apply **to them** and more donors get encouraged to support **them**.

Comment: Stylistically it's a terrible idea to include ***which*** here. Just delete it and start a new sentence after ***popularity***. Also note that idiomatically, *more donors **are** encouraged* is far better than slangy / sloppy ***get***.

Comment: when we can use "which" in such sentences?

Comment: *University faculties often appear on television, **which** gains them popularity and encourages more donors to support them*. Though I kinda doubt there would be much truth to that, since most "donors" (as opposed to ***students** paying course fees*) would be alumni (people who were educated at the university they're donating to). Such people hardly need to be reminded of their *alma mater* by seeing it on TV - mostly they'd have formed their social and professional circles at whatever uni they attended, so it's an ever-present factor in their lives anway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I try to retain majority of the original example and rephrase it.

The first part could be simplified, and *get encouraged to* could be omitted.

With this, one *them* could be omitted.

> By having their faculties on television, universities win popularity.  As a result, more students apply to, and more donors support, them.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot remove the second "them" while keeping the parallelism.

There are some other grammatical issues with the sentence. An edited version might be:

> When universities' faculty members appear on television, the universities receive publicity; as a result, more students apply to them and more donors are encouraged to support them.

If you wanted to remove both "them"s entirely, you could rewrite the sentence:

> When universities' faculty members appear on television, the universities benefit from increased student applications and donor support as a result of the publicity.

But if you use the parallel construction as you have in the original sentence, you need the pronoun "them" both times.